# Manually trigger validation error in input box using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box which is not part of a form. When a user clicks a button I want to display an error validation message if the field is empty. I found solutions for this when the input is part of a form, but is it possible to display validation error messages manually if the input box is not part of a form?

Comment: It looks like putting a `pattern` attribute will result in a *very missable* `Please match the requested format` as a *tooltip* (at least in Chrome), if the user happens to hover their mouse over the input afterwards, but that's pretty bad

Comment: See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp). Scroll down a bit to the "JavaScript Can Validate Numeric Input" section and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate in the button's click handler https://jsfiddle.net/yzgmpqLo/. I think it would be better to show invalidation message in the "input" field itself.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <script>

 function validateText() {
   var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtInput");
    if(txtInput.value.trim()=="") {       
      txtInput.value = "Invalid Entry";
      txtInput.style.color = "red";
    }else {
      txtInput.style.color = "black";
    }
 }

 </script>

 <input id="txtInput" type="text">
 <button type="button" onclick="validateText()">Validate</button>

</body>
</html>
```